# Can analytic continuation be applied to real functions? e.g. $f(x) = a\sin x + b\cos x$ in $[0,17]$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

I've a Fourier series up to the 3rd harmonic. It looks like this:
f(x) = 7.833333335 - 0.327444444*cos(0.349*x) - 0.882182222*cos(0.698*x) + 0.0000355555*cos(1.047*x) - 5.150566667*sin(0.349*x) - 2.298188889*sin(0.698*x) - 1.154688889*sin(1.047*x)

$f(x)$ is presently defined only on $[0, 17]$ (since it was derived from practical harmonic analysis).

I'd like to expand the domain of $f(x)$.

Can I do this using analytic continuation? (Considering my function has no imaginary part) If yes, how? If no, how else may I expand its domain?

Comment: The approximation $f$ is analytic and its analytic continuation looks exactly as what you have written, since that trigonometric polynomial is analytic in all of $\mathbb{C}$. The actual function of which $f$ is an approximation might not be analytic.

Comment: The idea that that function, _defined on_ $[0,17]$, is derived from "practical harmonic analysis" seems unlikely - one would expect a sum of terms $\cos(2\pi nt/17)$ and $\sin(2\pi nt/17)$. How does that derivation work, exactly?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh yes, my bad. That is the structure of the function.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I've updated it in the question. Could you please tell me what I could do to expand its domain?

Comment: Did you _read_ the first comment? To "expand the domain" you can just define f(x) = 7.833333335 - 0.327444444*cos(0.349*x) - 0.882182222*cos(0.698*x) + 0.0000355555*cos(1.047*x) - 5.150566667*sin(0.349*x) - 2.298188889*sin(0.698*x) - 1.154688889*sin(1.047*x) for all real x,

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I get what you're saying. But f(x) is just an approximation of some real data (which in fact goes from x = 0 to x = infinity). In saying "expand its domain", I was hoping for an approach which would accommodate for unseen real data. Does that make sense?